# React Native Memory Leak Issues appear in async function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i having an issues when render the useEffect with a async function which is the displayed as the picture below. It keeps appear everytime i refresh the application

[image]

This is the code what i implemented to get the accesstoken from the server side application

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getAccessToken() {
      const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
      console.log(typeof accessToken);
      setAccessToken((prev) => {
        return accessToken;
      });
    }

    getAccessToken();

    return async ()=> await getAccessToken()
  }, [accessToken, count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to React’s official documentation, “React performs the cleanup when the component unmounts. However… effects run for every render and not just once. This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.”

Below is a sample code which might work for you but can be further optimized.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isSubscribed = true;
  async function getAccessToken() {
    const accessToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access_token");
    console.log(typeof accessToken);
    if (isSubscribed) {
      setAccessToken((prev) => {
        return accessToken;
      });
    }
  }

  getAccessToken();

  return () => {
    // cancel the subscription
    isSubscribed = false;
  };
}, [accessToken, count]);
```

You can optimize it further by cancelling the fetch request after unmount.

I am not sure why but you component is somehow unmounting before the useEffect completes its state update logic. Thus it trying to update a state on unmounted component leading to memory leak.

For further explanation you can refer to [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-react-useeffect-cleanup-function/). This is great article which I found similar to your usecase.